# SKEmitterNode causing memory leak

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks, sprite-kit, skemitternode

I am programming a game using Xcode and test it on the iOS Simulator, using the Sprite Kit.

The `SKEmitterNode` I am using seems to cause a memory leak; when the game is running, each time `SKEmitterNode` is put on the screen (when drawing an 'explosion'), under the "Show the Debug Navigator" on left, the Memory increases without bound.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

The code below is all in `MYScene.m`.

My SKEmitterNode is called `_EmitterShatterApart` which is an explosion called "ShatterApart.sks". `_PositionObject` is an SKSpriteNode that is the object that is exploding. `_bgLayer` is the background layer.

```
@implementation MyScene
{
SKEmitterNode *_EmitterShatterApart;
...
}
-(void)MatchIncorrect
{
...
        _EmitterShatterApart = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ShatterApart" ofType:@"sks"]];
        _EmitterShatterApart.position = _PositionsObject.position;
        if (!_EmitterShatterApart.parent) {
            //[self.particleLayerNode addChild:_EmitterShatterApart];
            [_bgLayer addChild:_EmitterShatterApart];
            _EmitterShatterApart.userInteractionEnabled=FALSE;
            [_EmitterShatterApart resetSimulation];
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Before adding a new emitter, you  should remove the old one from the scene. Try with:

```
-(void)MatchIncorrect
{
    ...
    [_EmitterShatterApart removeFromParent];
    _EmitterShatterApart = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ShatterApart" ofType:@"sks"]];
    ...
```

If you do not do that, then you go on adding emitters to your scene, hence occupying memory without ever releasing it.